# ffmpeg rstp to rtmp with rtmp_conn

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, rtsp, rtmp

I trying to use next command:

```
ffmpeg -i link_to_rtsp -an -vcodec copy -f flv -rtmp_conn "my_options" -rtmp_live recorded link_to_rtmp
```

When I run it on Ubuntu this solution works wonderful, but when I run it on Windows XP/7 ffmpeg stopped on:

```
  Metadata:
    title           : RTSP/RTP stream 1 from DCS-2130
    comment         : live1.sdp
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuvj420p(pc), 640x480 [SAR
 fps, 25.08 tbr, 90k tbn, 150 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: adpcm_g726, 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 32 kb/s
```

Can somobody help me? Why ffmpeg on Windows don't run this command correctly? I try to use ffmpeg version 2.2.11, 2.4.2, 2.5.2, but still have this problem.

Comment: Are there any errors/warnings in the console output? Try increasing the log verbosity.

Comment: No, nothing in console or logs

Comment: Is `link_to_rtmp` accessible? Maybe you have something that blocks the communication and it waits for a timeout.

Comment: No, I check rtmp with rtmpdump, link_to_rtmp accessible. I run command with -report option and logs stopped at line:

`Parsing a group of options: output file rtmp://link_to_rtmp/

Applying option an (disable audio) with argument 1.

Applying option vcodec (force video codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument copy.

Applying option f (force format) with argument flv.

Successfully parsed a group of options.

Opening an output file: rtmp://link_to_rtmp/`

Comment: Could you give us the REAL command that you've made? I know that ffmpeg on Windows has a different behavior in particular with rtmp links, it does not support a link without **app name** like rtmp://127.0.0.1/stream, you need rather to write rtmp://127.0.0.1/app/stream (_app_ need to be the name of an existing application).

Comment: Yes, here is it:
`./ffmpeg -i "rtsp://192.168.0.10/onvif-media/media.amp?profile=profile_1_h264&sessiontimeout=60&streamtype=unicast" -an -vcodec copy -f flv -rtmp_conn "O:1 NS:apiKey:b86fd81d2861f1cd33f48c9768943d74 NS:cameraCode:f4202cab-629e-4f1d-bc4f-f60d9dd60165 NS:openId:https://twitter.com/my_twitter NS:streamType:live O:0" -rtmp_live recorded "rtmp://test-app.com:1935/app-streaming-server/media-stream-1428321007827"`